# Should I make extra pages for SEO that are not used within the website?

Tags: seo, google

I have a website with all the information about one city. One of the pages contains a complete overview of all the businesses in this area. For example: you can choose some categories like "Electrician" and then you see a list with all electricians. But this list is full AJAX with JS so I don't reload the whole page.

Should I make some URLs like `www.example.com/businesses/electricians` for SEO purposes only? When they search for electricians in this area the URL pop-ups in Google?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit further ?

Comment: What would you like to know more Nandla? I am not sure what else I can say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is a "landing page". They are great for SEO and I would strongly recommend them for your website. It would be best if you could code it in such a way that any new electricians (for example) are automatically included, it would save you a lot of editing time adding and deleting companies on all of your pages. You should consider them for every business variety (plumbing, accounting, etc.) if at all possible.

Comment: Yes, the website is programmed that everything comes from a database and my sitemap is generated so whenever there is a new business or category it will include the url automatically. Where do I need to pay attention to if I DONT want to make it a doorway page like Harper said?

Comment: If I understand the concept of the page, it isn't going to be a different principle than the yellowpages would offer. You are providing a local search service for the business people of your site. That is very focused, based on geographic location, and on a site that offers tons of information about that specific area. As long as you have other things on the page (like today's weather) in an "aside" or on the side, you should be safe. Even better if the electricians links lead to a page that provides the electrician contact info and from there a link to their website.

Comment: You are right Elbrant. All businesses also have profilepages with specific information about them. The page I would make will be part of the website but will ONLY be accesible when searching via google or when someone on Facebook asks for electricians I can just link them a specific url with everyone on it.

Comment: By "only accessable when" do you mean that the information is produced "on the fly"? Is the link going to be `example.com/businesses/electricians/`, or more like `example.com/scripts?biz=electricians`?

Comment: Maybe what I should ask, is what language are you using?

Comment: The website is developed in .NET ASP MVC. The link will be example.com/businesses/id/categoryname/. So it will work for all categories.

Comment: You can check out the website here : https://www.mijngistel.be/zelfstandigen/gids/ but it is all in dutch tho.

Comment: Looks like you are on the right track. :) (my ancesters were from Amsterdam, doesn't mean I can speak Dutch, but...)

Answer (score 1):

Those are called **doorway pages** and are one of the most basic violations of search engine rules.  A doorway is a page loaded with juicy text content where the user isn't really expected to spend any time *engaging the content*, the content is strictly for search engine juice and the user is expected to bounce very quickly onto some other content.

Of course if you are using technical means to steer the user away from the indexed content, such as hidden text, screen overlays, redirects, or pushing it way down the page... All the worse.

Generally speaking, if you are doing significant things to your websites *just for search engines*, you're on the wrong road.

Comment: But what if they do spend time on the page and dont see any difference if they search "Electricians" from the website?

Comment: If someone visits from the search engine, do you want them using the static page or the search result?

Comment: the search result but if they find the static page via google they should also use the same search engine. Do I understand it correctly?